# expo-development-client cannot find android sdk despite ANDROID_SDK_ROOT being set as an env variable and in the Android SDK manager

Tags: android, build, expo, eas

Just as the title says.

- I've triple checked that the `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` is set as an environment variable from my `~/.zshrc` file, have sourced it, and verified it's available right before I run `expo run:android`.
- I've set the path in the Android SDK Manager's SDK location.
- I've `updated expo-development-client`
- I've ran `expo doctor`
- I restarted the android simulator using a cold boot start
- I checked the permissions of the the Android and sdk folders, both are marked as executables and have the permissions set to my user and staff.

Contents of the `~/Library/Android/sdk` folder:

```
build-tools    cmdline-tools  emulator       
licenses       patcher        platform-tools 
platforms      skins          sources        
system-images
```

Versions:

- MacOS Monterey 12.4
- Laptop is a late 2021 Apple M1 Pro
- node v16.17.0

Package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0",
    "@miblanchard/react-native-slider": "^2.1.0",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.0.5",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.4.3",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.2",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.1.0",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.2",
    "awesome-debounce-promise": "^2.1.0",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "babel-plugin-dotenv-import": "^2.2.0",
    "expo": "~45.0.0",
    "expo-asset": "~8.5.0",
    "expo-constants": "~13.1.1",
    "expo-dev-client": "~1.0.1",
    "expo-font": "~10.1.0",
    "expo-linking": "~3.1.0",
    "expo-secure-store": "~11.2.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.15.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.3.0",
    "expo-web-browser": "~10.2.1",
    "hooks": "^0.3.2",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.33.0",
    "react-native": "0.68.2",
    "react-native-confirmation-code-field": "^7.3.0",
    "react-native-dropdown-picker": "^5.4.2",
    "react-native-email": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.2.1",
    "react-native-modal-dropdown": "^1.0.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "2.8.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.2.4",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.11.1",
    "react-native-svg": "12.3.0",
    "react-native-swipe-list-view": "^3.2.9",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.7",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.2",
    "rithmm-api-client-ts": "^0.42.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@svgr/webpack": "^6.3.1",
    "@types/react": "~17.0.21",
    "@types/react-native": "~0.67.6",
    "@types/react-native-modal-dropdown": "^0.7.2",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.6",
    "@types/styled-components-react-native": "^5.1.3",
    "expo-cli": "^5.5.1",
    "expo-updates": "^0.13.3",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "jest-expo": "^45.0.0",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.3.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2",
    "typescript": "~4.3.5"
  },
```